# Flutter WebRTC server is not letting me connect

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I recently started using flutter to create an app that has video and audio calling, so I thought of using WebRTC to accomplish this. However, when I tried to create a local WebRTC server from the WebRTC Github it doesn't let me connect to it. When I run the server from the command prompt it tells me that the server is listening at the given local IP, but when I try to connect to it, it says the site can't be reached. Also when I ping the url it says the ping request could not find the host. Any kind of help would really be appreciated.

WebRTC server: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-server

[Starting server in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWpZi.png)

[netstat when server running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOepb.jpg)

[pinging server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnIFK.png)

Comment: Post the errors received in the question along with the github link for WebRTC

Comment: Are you able to access the url from browser?

Answer (score 1):

The IP 0.0.0.0 is not the IP address the server is binding/listening too.

It is a common way that servers allow configurion 0.0.0.0 to express binding to all IPv4 the host has (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0 ). To acually reach your server use whatever IP you have on the host (if you are starting the server on your workstation 127.0.0.1 ought to work)

Ping on Windows is only ICMP if I am not mistaken, this means a TCP port number is not part of it's expected input. Eg. "0.0.0.0:8086" is not a valid target for that command  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping )

```
>ping 0.0.0.0:8086
Ping request could not find host 0.0.0.0:8086. Please check the name and try again.

>ping 0.0.0.0

Pinging 0.0.0.0 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 0.0.0.0:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 0, Lost = 2 (100% loss),
Control-C
^C
>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
^C
```

Since what you are trying to connect to is a webserver you could use something like curl instead to try to verify your connection. Should be available without any further install if you are on Windows 10 1803 or newer.

```
>curl https://0.0.0.0:8086
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8086: Address not available
>curl https://127.0.0.1:8086
<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1></body></html>
```

Some browsers might support https://0.0.0.0:8086 in a similar way server do but I wouldn't rely on it. Go with https://127.0.0.1:8086 or a non localhost IP address of the host.

Answer (score 0):

```
    flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.8
    sdp_transform: ^0.3.2
    firebase_core: ^1.24.0
    firebase_auth: ^3.11.1
    cloud_firestore: ^3.5.0
    cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.1
    flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.3+1
    google_fonts: ^3.0.1
    flutter_svg: ^1.1.5
 

    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

    typedef StreamStateCallback = void Function(MediaStream stream);

    class Signaling {
    Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
    'iceServers': [
      {
        'urls': [
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  final Map<String, dynamic> offerSdpConstraints = {
    "mandatory": {
      "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
      "OfferToReceiveVideo": true,
    },
    "optional": [],
  };

  RTCPeerConnection? peerConnection;
  MediaStream? localStream;
  MediaStream? remoteStream;
  String? roomId;
  String? currentRoomText;
  StreamStateCallback? onAddRemoteStream;

  Future<String> createRoom(RTCVideoRenderer remoteRenderer) async {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    DocumentReference roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc();
    final activecallers = db.collection('ActiveCallers');

    print('Create PeerConnection with configuration: $configuration');

    peerConnection =
        await createPeerConnection(configuration, offerSdpConstraints);
    // peerConnection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);

    registerPeerConnectionListeners();

    localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {
      peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
    });

    // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
    var callerCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('callerCandidates');

    peerConnection?.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
      print('Got candidate: ${candidate.toMap()}');
      callerCandidatesCollection.add(candidate.toMap());
    };
    // Finish Code for collecting ICE candidate

    // Add code for creating a room
    RTCSessionDescription offer = await peerConnection!.createOffer();
    await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(offer);
    print('Created offer: $offer');

    Map<String, dynamic> roomWithOffer = {'offer': offer.toMap()};

    await roomRef.set(roomWithOffer);
    var roomId = roomRef.id;
    print('New room created with SDK offer. Room ID: $roomId');
    currentRoomText = 'Current room is $roomId - You are the caller!';
    // Created a Room

    peerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
      print('Got remote track: ${event.streams[0]}');

      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) {
        print('Add a track to the remoteStream $track');
        remoteStream?.addTrack(track);
      });
    };

    //add in active user list
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _activeUserCollRef.get();
    // Get data from docs and convert map to List
    int aciveusercount =
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList().length + 1;
    final acitvecallerjson = {
      'id': roomId,
      'name': 'user_$aciveusercount',
      'start-on': DateTime.now()
    };
    activecallers.add(acitvecallerjson);
    // Listening for remote session description below
    roomRef.snapshots().listen((snapshot) async {
      print('Got updated room: ${snapshot.data()}');

      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (peerConnection?.getRemoteDescription() != null &&
          data['answer'] != null) {
        var answer = RTCSessionDescription(
          data['answer']['sdp'],
          data['answer']['type'],
        );

        print("Someone tried to connect");
        await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(answer);
      }
    });
    // Listening for remote session description above

    // Listen for remote Ice candidates below
    roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = change.doc.data() as Map<String, 
          dynamic>;
          //print('Got new remote ICE candidate: ${jsonEncode(data)}');
          peerConnection!.addCandidate(
            RTCIceCandidate(
              data['candidate'],
              data['sdpMid'],
              data['sdpMLineIndex'],
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    });
    // Listen for remote ICE candidates above

    return roomId;
  }

  final CollectionReference _activeUserCollRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ActiveCallers');

  Future<List> getData() async {
    // Get docs from collection reference
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _activeUserCollRef.get();

    // Get data from docs and convert map to List
    List listData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(
        'datalist================================================================');
    print(listData.length);
    return listData;
  }

  Future<void> joinRoom(String roomId, RTCVideoRenderer remoteVideo) async {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    DocumentReference roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc('$roomId');
    var roomSnapshot = await roomRef.get();
    print('Got room ${roomSnapshot.exists}');

    if (roomSnapshot.exists) {
      print('Create PeerConnection with configuration: $configuration');
      peerConnection = await createPeerConnection(configuration);

      registerPeerConnectionListeners();

      localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {
        peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
      });

      // Code for collecting ICE candidates below
      var calleeCandidatesCollection = 
      roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates');
      peerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
        if (candidate == null) {
          print('onIceCandidate: complete!');
          return;
        }
        print('onIceCandidate: ${candidate.toMap()}');
        calleeCandidatesCollection.add(candidate.toMap());
      };
      // Code for collecting ICE candidate above

      peerConnection?.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
        print('Got remote track: ${event.streams[0]}');
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) {
          print('Add a track to the remoteStream: $track');
          remoteStream?.addTrack(track);
        });
      };

      // Code for creating SDP answer below
      var data = roomSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('Got offer $data');
      var offer = data['offer'];
      await peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(
        RTCSessionDescription(offer['sdp'], offer['type']),
      );
      var answer = await peerConnection!.createAnswer();
      print('Created Answer $answer');

      await peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(answer);

      Map<String, dynamic> roomWithAnswer = {
        'answer': {'type': answer.type, 'sdp': answer.sdp}
      };

      await roomRef.update(roomWithAnswer);
      // Finished creating SDP answer

      // Listening for remote ICE candidates below
      roomRef.collection('callerCandidates').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges.forEach((document) {
          var data = document.doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          print(data);
          print('Got new remote ICE candidate: $data');
          peerConnection!.addCandidate(
            RTCIceCandidate(
              data['candidate'],
              data['sdpMid'],
              data['sdpMLineIndex'],
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> openUserMedia(
    RTCVideoRenderer localVideo,
    RTCVideoRenderer remoteVideo,
  ) async {
    var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({'video': true, 'audio': true});

    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    localStream = stream;

    remoteVideo.srcObject = await createLocalMediaStream('key');
  }

  Future<void> hangUp(RTCVideoRenderer localVideo) async {
    List<MediaStreamTrack> tracks = localVideo.srcObject!.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach((track) {
      track.stop();
    });

    if (remoteStream != null) {
      remoteStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    if (peerConnection != null) peerConnection!.close();

    if (roomId != null) {
      var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      var roomRef = db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId);
      var calleeCandidates = await 
      roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').get();
      calleeCandidates.docs.forEach((document) => 
      document.reference.delete());

      var callerCandidates = await 
      roomRef.collection('callerCandidates').get();
      callerCandidates.docs.forEach((document) => 
      document.reference.delete());

      await roomRef.delete();
    }

    localStream!.dispose();
    remoteStream?.dispose();
  }

  void registerPeerConnectionListeners() {

    peerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {
      print('ICE gathering state changed: $state');
    };

    peerConnection?.onConnectionState = (RTCPeerConnectionState state) {
      print('Connection state change: $state');
    };

    peerConnection?.onSignalingState = (RTCSignalingState state) {
      print('Signaling state change: $state');
    };

    peerConnection?.onIceGatheringState = (RTCIceGatheringState state) {
      print('ICE connection state change: $state');
    };

    peerConnection?.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
      print("Add remote stream");
      onAddRemoteStream?.call(stream);
      remoteStream = stream;
    };

  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).